# Что означают фргументы: win_type='triang' win_type='gaussian' win_type='exponential' в rolling pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Пытался гуглить но ничего кроме описаний не нашел. Возвращает треугольник, окно Гауса... Что это значит и как это воздействует на числа? Какая формула применяется в расчетах? Объясните по-простому пожалуйста.

Comment: В документации же есть ссылка вот сюда, читайте здесь про функции https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.windows.html#module-scipy.signal.windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем документацию на [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), читаем:

**win_type** `str`, default `None`
If `None`, all points are evenly weighted.
If a string, it must be a valid scipy.signal window function.

Ну то есть если параметр `None`, то все точки окна имеют одинаковый вес, а если там строка, то используется оконная функция.

Открываем ссылку и читаем что пишут в [scipy.signal.windows](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.windows.html#module-scipy.signal.windows), например, открываем там дальше описание [gaussian](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.gaussian.html#scipy.signal.windows.gaussian).

Там приведена формула и даже график нарисован.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при таком типе окна используется Гауссово или **нормальное** распределение. Точки в середине окна имеют наибольший вес 1, по краям - наименьший 0, а в целом как распределены веса - см. график.

И так можно посмотреть информацию по всем интересующим вас оконным функциям, например [exponential](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.exponential.html#scipy.signal.windows.exponential)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]